# Number of solutions of $x+\frac{87}x=\lfloor x\rfloor+\frac{87}{\lfloor x\rfloor} $ where $x\in\mathbb{Q} , x\notin\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: contest-math, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How many solutions the equation $x+\frac{87}x=\lfloor x\rfloor+\frac{87}{\lfloor x\rfloor} $ has in rational non integer sets of numbers?

$1)\text{zero}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad2)1\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad3
)2\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad4)87\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad5)\text{infinity}$

So the solution can't be an integer therefore $\lfloor x\rfloor\ne x$ and generally we can say $\lfloor x\rfloor< x$. also denominator of the fractions can't be zero so  $\lfloor x\rfloor \neq0$ hence $x\notin[0,1)$

I wrote the equation as:

$$x-\lfloor x\rfloor=\frac{87}{\lfloor x \rfloor}-\frac{87}{x}=\frac{87(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)}{x\lfloor x\rfloor}$$

But can't see a way to continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track.

**Hint 1:** Divide both sides by $(x - \lfloor x \rfloor)$

**Hint 2:** Note that for $\lfloor x\rfloor \geq 0$,
$$
\lfloor x\rfloor^2 \leq \lfloor x\rfloor x \leq \lfloor x\rfloor(\lfloor x\rfloor + 1).
$$

Comment: Ok, then we get $x\lfloor x\rfloor=87$ so  multiplication of a non integer rational number and an integer is equal to $87$ can we say there is no solution?

Comment: @amirali $4 \cdot \frac 52 = 10$ is an example where a non-integer rational number and an integer are multiplied to yield an integer, so your line of reasoning is incorrect.

Comment: So $87=3\times29$ and we should have both of these factors in numerator.

Comment: @amirali I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: From the second hint I realized $\lfloor x\rfloor =9$ therefore $x=\frac {87}9$ is a solution. and I guess there is no solution for $\lfloor x\rfloor <0$

Comment: @ami I actually forgot that $x$ is allowed to be negative. Your guess is correct, but it's something that you should verify

Answer (score 2):

$$x+\frac{87}x=\lfloor x\rfloor+\frac{87}{\lfloor x\rfloor}$$

Let $x = n + \delta$ where $x \in \Bbb Z$ and $\delta \in (0,1)$

$$n+\frac{87}n=(n+\delta)+\frac{87}{n+\delta}$$

$$(n+\delta)(n^2 + 87) = n((n+\delta)^2 + 87) $$

$$n^3 + \delta n^2 + 87n + 87 \delta = n^3 + 2 \delta n^2 + \delta^2 n + 87n$$

$$\delta n^2 + \delta^2 n - 87\delta = 0$$

$$\delta n = 87-n^2$$

If $n > 0$

$$ 0 \lt 87 - n^2 < n$$

$$n \in \{1,2,\dots, 9\} \wedge n \in \{9, 10, \dots   \}$$
$$ n = 9$$

If $n < 0$

$$ n < 87-n^2 < 0$$

$$n \in \{-9, -8, \dots, -1\} \wedge n \in \{\dots -12,-11, -10\}$$

$$n \in \emptyset$$

For $n = 9$ we get $\delta = \dfrac{87-n^2}{n} = \dfrac 23$.

So the only solution is $x = 9\frac 23 = \frac{29}{3}$.